# Conditional concatenation in batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I am trying to append an underscore to strings when they are not blank. This is for a backup program, where the name of the folder is `[prefix]_[date]_[time]_[suffix]`, except the first and last underscores are supposed to only be added when the `[prefix]` or `[suffix]` are not empty.

I've attempted to concatenate with `set PRX=%PRX% and _` as I read on some forum, although the and wasn't recognized (it just outputted "backup and _"). I also tried jumping around the files with "goto", but to no avail. I think it's with the concatenation.

```
@echo off

set /p DRV=Enter drive/directory to back up (e.g. %userprofile% or C:): 
set /p DRU=Enter directory to save to (e.g. C:\backup or F:): 
set /p PRX=Enter the prefix for the directory. Directory will be saved as [prefix]_[date]_[time]_[suffix]: 
set /p SFX=Enter the suffix for the directory. Directory will be saved as [prefix]_[date]_[time]_[suffix]: 

if %PRX% NEQ "" (set PRX=%PRX%_)

if %SFX% NEQ "" (set SFX=_%SFX%)

set /p CONT=%CD%, Are you sure you want to continue (Y/N)? 
if /i "%CONT%" EQU "N" goto :cancel

cls

echo Initialising...

%DRV:~0,1%:
cd\

set DAT=%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%
set TIM=%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%

mkdir "%DRU%\%PRX%%DAT%_%TIM%%SFX%"

echo Cloning Files...
echo.

xcopy "%DRV%\*" "%DRU%\%PRX%%DAT%_%TIM%%SFX%" /s
```

I inputted

```
Enter drive/directory to back up (e.g. %userprofile% or C:): %userprofile%\downloads

Enter directory to save to (e.g. C:\backup or F:): %userprofile%\backup

Enter the prefix for the directory. Directory will be saved as [prefix]_[date]_[time]_[suffix]: (that is empty)

Enter the suffix for the directory. Directory will be saved as [prefix]_[date]_[time]_[suffix]: aa
```

the outputted folder was named `"_2019-09-10_17-08-35_aa"` as opposed to `"2019-09-10_17-08-35_aa"`, not what I was expecting.

I appreciate any reply, thank you for your time.

Comment: Change `if %PRX% NEQ "" (set PRX=%PRX%_)` => `if defined PRX set "PRX=%PRX%"` otherwise this line returns an error on empty input. Same with SFX.

Comment: Also why do you give the choice to enter a directory with `DRV` when you ignore it? Your date time substring relies on locale/user settings, better use WMIC/PwerShell to get a consistent date time.

Comment: Quote both parts of the comparison, like `if "%PRX%" neq "" ...`, or use `if defined PRX ...`...

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

String comparison is very explicit.

```
IF "%PRX%" NEQ "" (SET "PRX=%PRX%_")
IF "%SFX%" NEQ "" (SET "SFX=_%SFX%")
```

It is easy to get correctly formatted data and time values regardless of region settings.

```
FOR /F %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'"') DO (
    SET "DAT=%%A"
)
FOR /F %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-Date -Format 'HH-mm-ss'"') DO (
    SET "TIM=%%A"
)
```